# Opening google earth api in mobile web browser

Tags: google-api, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I wrote a web site with google earth api and it is working fine.
I want to open this site via mobile browser, and it's giving me the following error: 
"the plug-in of google earth is available only for win and mac".
How can i get through it?

Thanks.
:)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Google Earth Plugin and [Google Earth API](https://developers.google.com/earth/) is currently only supported on the Windows and Mac platforms.

Full list of which OS versions and browsers are supported can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/index#installing_the_google_earth_plugin

The mobile version as well as the Linux version of Google Earth does not currently support the Google Earth plugin.

If you redesign your web site using [Google Maps V3 APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) then it would be supported by mobile and desktop web browsers. Google Earth is a thick desktop and has restrictions especially with respect to mobile devices that a pure web application such as using Google Maps APIs can avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue.  I wish to try and use Android WebView instead of setting up GooglePlayServices at this time for an art project

I have the example loading just fine on Windows and Mac, but I need this for my Android art project.

My source code can be viewed at this link below:

[www.rennakanote.com/earthdraw](http://rennakanote.com/earthdraw.html)

[image: I am having the same issue here and will update this page when I find the solution.]

I will attempt to see what I can try from Google Maps V3 APIs as per your instruction JasonM1 and see if I find a way to load this in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Although the Google Earth **plugin** doesn't work on mobile devices, both Android and iOS devices have a Google Earth app available for them.

Thus a good way to show your data on both desktop and mobile devices is simply to publish it as a KML file, which will load in all versions of the program.  The mobile devices don't actually offer a "load file" option, but instead rely on the fact that if you present the device with a KML file with the correct mime type, then the system works out that the Google Earth app is the appropriate one to display the file.